# Property does not exist in self-referencing interface implementation in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am still new at Typescript, can someone explain to me where I did wrong here? Is it expected behavior or bug?

```js
// interfaces/ValueObject.ts

export interface ValueObject {
  equals<T extends ValueObject> (valueObject: T): boolean;
  toString (): string;
}
```

```js
// values/Age.ts

export class Age implements ValueObject {
  constructor (
    public readonly value: number,
  ) {}

  equals<Age> (anotherAge: Age): boolean {
    return anotherAge.value === this.value;
  }

  toString () {
    return `${this.value} year{this.value === 1 ? '' : 's'} old`;
  }
}
```

Somehow I got the following error on compilation: `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Age'.` But I did declare the property value in the constructor, did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `equals<Age> (anotherAge: Age): boolean` the `<Age>` introduces a new type parameter `Age`. This means that the `Age` in the parameter definition is not the class `Age` you are defining, but rather the type parameter you introduced in the function.

From what I can tell, you actually want the interface to take a parameter of the same type as the implementing class. To do this in Typescript we can use polymorphic `this`

```
export interface ValueObject {
    equals(valueObject: this): boolean;
    toString(): string;
}

export class Age implements ValueObject {
    constructor(
        public readonly value: number,
    ) { }

    equals(anotherAge: Age): boolean {
        return anotherAge.value === this.value;
    }

    toString() {
        return `${this.value} year{this.value === 1 ? '' : 's'} old`;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is actually, something that I want to do, creating an interface where the class that implements the interface should compare with itself. I thought generic is the way to go, I guess simple `this` would suffice. I guess I think too far.
Just want to make sure, will there be a way to do this with generic?